# django friends model with circle - choose best way - different approaches provided

Tags: python, django, database-design

First proposal:
Friendinvitemodel containing invitation data that.
Friend model containing friends data in this way:

```
FriendModel(models.Model):
    user = foreignkey..
    friend = fkey ...
    circle = foreignkey ..
```

So, here let us assume, we have 3 users, usera, userb, userc. usera, userb are friends. userb, userc are friends. usera, userc are friends. Then, we have 6 records here like this:

```
    Record 1: user = usera, friend=userb
    Record 2 : user = usera, friend=userc
    Record 3: user = userb, friend=usera
    Record 4 : user = userb, friend=userc
    Record 5: user = userc, friend=usera
    Record 6 : user = userc, friend=userb
```

I know records doubled here, but just for the sake for making "circle" work correctly, I have given like this.

Second proposal:

There wont be Friend model, only Circle will be there

```
  class Circle(models.Model):
       user = foreignkey...
       json = json data comes here
```

So, here what I am doing is, for every user, an object will be created here, with his friends list in this json data.

Which approach do u feel good? first or second ? Also, is the json plan makes fetching mutual friends difficult ?

Ok then, in both approaches, we have to fetch user information too when fetching users, so, this is my plan .  Cache every user's userprofile and userobject FOREVER and whenever user object or userprofile obj is modified, we trigger someway to refresh cache for that instance. How can we do this ?

One idea i have for this is, store modified user id in some memory or redis kind of fast database. We write a decorator that checks if request id is in the list of modified userids. If available, then it will be fetched from database and that key is deleted from list of modified userids. If not available, it will simple show from cache. But not sure, how to dot this.